# Bing maps 7.0 not displaying near by location in road/aerial view

Tags: bing-maps

I am using [bing map 7.0 api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427606.aspx) to display location of an user in the site. 
Near by location information is missing when I am using it in my application.
Please let me know what I am missing or am I doing something wrong?

Please find the details below.

The below image is from bing site for a location in New Delhi, India.

[BingMap link for given location](http://www.bing.com/maps/#Y3A9MjguNjEzOTAwfjc3LjIwODkwMCZsdmw9MTImc3R5PXImcT0yOC42MTM5MDAwJTJDJTIwNzcuMjA4OTAwMA==)

Please note the red square on the map showing near by location.

[image]

Now when i am trying to locate a same point in my application these near by location information are missing.

Adding image from my site to clarify. Only Road information are shown.
[image]

Here is how I am using it in my application.
Map reference added as:
 `<script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0">
</script>`

Map is initialized as:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("MapDiv"),
   {
       credentials: "My Bing Key",
       center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location("latitude", longitude),
       mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
       zoom: 16
   });
```

I am using Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin to mark a location.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bing Maps API's does not currently turn on all point of interest data on the map layer. The reason for this is most users of the API's are companies and the last thing any company wants is to show a competitor on their website via the map.